# How to combine two sql queries into one

Tags: sql

How can I combine these two SQL statements?

```
SELECT SUM(hits01 + hits02 + hits03 + hits04 + hits05 + hits06 + hits07 + hits08 + hits09) AS 'AEROwiz'
FROM tbl_2011
WHERE appName='AEROwiz'

SELECT SUM(hits10 + hits11 + hits12) AS 'AEROwiz'
FROM tbl_2010
WHERE appName='AEROwiz'
```

hits10, hits11 and hits12 exist in both tables.

Comment: Can you upload the schemas for your tables?

Comment: Question is unclear, are you asking about a UNION?

Comment: What do you mean by combine? Do you want one row with two columns? Two rows with one column? What should the result be?

Comment: I want to do one query that gives me both sums combined into one sum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a UNION query - just stuff "UNION" between the two queries:

```
SELECT SUM(...) AS AEROWiz
FROM ...

UNION

SELECT SUM(...) AS AEROWiz
FROM ...
```

---

update

wrap the union in yet another query:

```
SELECT SUM(AEROWiz)
FROM (
    .... unioned queries here
) AS child
```

Comment: I want to do one query that gives me both sums combined into one sum.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  SUM(hits01 + hits02 + hits03 + hits04 + hits05 + hits06 +  
hits07 + hits08 + hits09) AS 'AEROwiz' 
FROM    tbl_2011 
WHERE   appName='AEROwiz' 

UNION ALL

SELECT  SUM(hits10 + hits11 + hits12) AS 'AEROwiz' 
FROM    tbl_2010 
WHERE   appName='AEROwiz'
```

Use `UNION ALL` as it will allow duplicates, and `UNION` will not put duplicates in the query result.  With the `SUM()` aggregate, I'm guessing there's a good chance of duplication summations, so I'd go with `UNION ALL` for this one.

Comment: @JonH: No... *`UNION`* does that. `UNION ALL` is almost certainly what he wants. Though he probably also wants to know which row is which.

Comment: @JonH you have that backwards.  `UNION ALL` does NOT remove duplicates, `UNION` does.

Comment: UNION removes duplicates but UNION ALL does not.

Comment: Sorry i always mix the two deleted the comment.

Comment: I need the sums of both tables to be added together.

Comment: This solution provided me with both sums, but is there a way I can add them together in the query???

Answer (score 2):

You could use two subselects:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT SUM(hits01 + hits02 + hits03 + hits04 + hits05 + hits06 + hits07 + hits08 + hits09)
    FROM tbl_2011
    WHERE appName='AEROwiz'
) T1
+
(
    SELECT SUM(hits10 + hits11 + hits12)
    FROM tbl_2010
    WHERE appName='AEROwiz'
) T2
AS AEROwiz
```

You may also want to consider normalizing your database so that you don't have a table for each year.

Comment: I want to do one query that gives me both sums combined into one sum.

Comment: @Anthony: That's exactly what this is.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  SUM(hits01 + hits02 + hits03 + hits04 + hits05 + hits06 + 
hits07 + hits08 + hits09 + t2010.hits10 + t2010.hits11 + t2010.hits12) AS 'AEROwiz'
FROM tbl_2010 t2010
JOIN tbl_2011 t2011 ON t2010.appName = t2011.appName
WHERE t2010.appName='AEROwiz'
```

Comment: I want to do one query that gives me both sums combined into one sum.