# Combine the results of two SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How can I combine the results of these two sql queries either in SQL or PHP .. they're all involving joins .. I would like to combine them both and sort them by orderid .. how can I do that ?

**first query**

```
$sqlstr = "SELECT op.* FROM products_to_products_extra_fields AS p 
    INNER JOIN orders_roster AS r ON p.products_id = r.products_id 
    INNER JOIN orders_products AS op ON r.orders_id = op.orders_id
    INNER JOIN orders AS o on op.orders_id = o.orders_id
    WHERE p.products_extra_fields_id = 14
      AND p.products_extra_fields_value between '" 
         . tep_db_input($startdate) . "' and '" 
         . tep_db_input($enddate) . " 23:59:59'
      AND r.roster_status != 'Removed'
      AND o.payment_method = 'Institutional Billing'
      AND o.orders_status < 100001
    GROUP BY o.orders_id
    ORDER BY DECODE(o.cc_type, '$salt') ASC";
```

**SECOND query**

```
$sqlstr2 = "SELECT op.* FROM products_to_products_extra_fields AS p 
    INNER JOIN orders_products AS op ON p.products_id = op.products_id 
    INNER JOIN orders AS o on op.orders_id = o.orders_id
    WHERE p.products_id IN 
      (SELECT products_id 
        FROM products_to_products_extra_fields 
        WHERE p.products_id NOT IN 
          (SELECT products_id 
           FROM products_to_products_extra_fields 
           WHERE products_extra_fields_id = 14)
      )
      AND o.date_purchased between '" 
         . tep_db_input($startdate) . "' and '" 
         . tep_db_input($enddate) . " 23:59:59'
      AND o.payment_method = 'Institutional Billing'
      AND o.orders_status < 100001
    GROUP BY o.orders_id
    ORDER BY DECODE(o.cc_type, '$salt') ASC";
```

Comment: Do you have to run them as separate queries?  If so, do they have the exact same columns in them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine two sql queries into one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972015/how-to-combine-two-sql-queries-into-one)

Comment: `(select foo as bar) union all (select baz) order by bar`

Comment: Depends on how you want them combined.  a simple UNION would be the first option.

Comment: Yes I have to run them separately ... then combine the results in php ..

Comment: @Andrew: since both queries use `SELECT *` to draw from the same table, `orders_products`, we conclude they have the same columns.

Comment: Then yes, as several people have suggested, you should be able to union the results together.

Answer (score 2):

If you need them combined on the PHP end, I am going to assume you are left with an array of arrays (MySQL Rows), which you could simply loop through both sets of results and use array_push to push them into 3rd(complete) array. You could also toy around with array_merge but sometimes with multidimensional arrays the end result isnt what you expected.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php
https://www.php.net/function.array-merge

Comment: As for sorting them by orderid once they are all merged check out array_multisort

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Answer (score 2):

Just make a UNION query and get the results merged on the SQL side. No PHP needed.

Comment: There are two answers so far.  +1 for both.  But Joseph Lust's approach is more pure.  Do your real work with SQL first, and the final process will be more scalable, more sound.  (Of course, you can build badly with SQL...)